# AJAX update and delete error but still successful error

Tags: php, ajax

**
I have a problem when updating and deleting, when I incorrectly enter the column id, although the database does not change, the system still reports
success **

```
$loai = trim($_POST['loai']);
 $id = trim($_POST['id']);
    $ten = trim($_POST['ten']);
    $idghichu = trim($_POST['idghichu']);
$sql;
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','12345678','chamcomvantay');
if($loai == "xoa") {
$sql = "DELETE FROM chamcomvantay.tb_bophan WHERE ID='$id' ";
 }
elseif ($loai == "sua") {
    $sql = "UPDATE chamcomvantay.tb_bophan SET TENBP='$ten', GHICHU='$idghichu' WHERE ID='$id'   ";
}
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

echo "success";    // This is an error //

 } else {
  echo "Lỗi";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

```
--my ajax code---- 

$idbophan  = $('#idbophan').val();   
$idten =  $('#idten').val();
$idghichu = $('#idghichu').val();
$loai = "sua";
if($idbophan.trim() != "" ){
$.post('thaotacbophan.php',{'id':$idbophan.trim(),'ten': $idten.trim(),'idghichu':$idghichu.trim(),'loai':$loai.trim()}, function(data){
alert(data); // error but still alert("success"); ///
  });
}
else{
  alert("Vui lòng điền đầy đủ thông tin");
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_query` return false only on failure, in your case, even when there is no change to the database, the query is till successful, it just didn't update/delete any row from the database since the id does not match. To get the number of record affected by your query, you can use [mysqli_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: use `mysqli_affected_rows` to check if any row is affected for both cases

Comment: can you demo with your code?